# three20 framework integration?

Tags: iphone, three20

Please, advice me how safe is to integrate three20 framework in our project. Previously i heard that some private API issue and apple rejecting the app. Did any one done the three20 framework and apple approve it with out any issue ?

Please, advice ASAP.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone App rejected because of Three20 "non-public API" "lineHeight" and "previousViewController"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865778/iphone-app-rejected-because-of-three20-non-public-api-lineheight-and-previou)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Three20 in my own apps and they have been approved. The offending private API usage has been removed in the later versions of Three20.

Check http://three20.info for the current app store status.